# wix react native navigation registerComponent React is not defined

Tags: redux, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

In react-native-navigation 7.14.0, the `Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux` has been deprecated and it suggested that **registerComponentWithRedux is deprecated** and will be removed in the next version! Please **use Navigation.registerComponent instead**. Visit the docs for more information https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/api/component#registering-a-component-wrapped-with-providers

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const store = createStore();

Navigation.registerComponent(`navigation.playground.MyScreen`, () => (props) =>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyScreen {...props} />
  </Provider>,
  () => MyScreen)
);
```

It was working fine with **registerComponentWithRedux** with the deprecated warning. To get rid of the warning, I changed registerComponentWithRedux to the following and it crashed on app launched with **React is not defined**. Am I doing something wrong or there is a bug for registerComponent with redux provider?

```js
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

Navigation.registerComponent(ScreenEnum.HOME_SCREEN, () => (props) =>
<Provider store={store}>
  <HomeScren {...props} />
</Provider>,
() => HomeScren);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

Navigation.registerComponent(ScreenEnum.HOME_SCREEN, () => (props) =>
<Provider store={store}>
  <HomeScreen {...props} />
</Provider>,
() => HomeScreen);
```

Also note in your second example your `HomeScreen` component is mispelled.

Comment: Thanks, bring in `import React from 'react';` worked, good catch about the misspelled HomeScren, but that was just a misspell, not the cause for the crash. Not seeing React is being used anywhere in the code other than just importing it here, do you mind to explain what's going on?